# How to get data using ajax passing parameter (laravel)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I want to fill a table by doing a SQL query that has a where `id = $id`.

code ajax:

```
$('#ingredientTable').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "api/ingredients",
        "type": "post",
         "data" : {
             '_token': token,
              "id" :  '1' ,
          }
    },
    "columns":[
      {data:'name', name: 'ingredients.name'},
    ],
});
```

In the route:

```
route::post('api/ingredients', function() {
    return Datatables::of(
        DB::select('SELECT * FROM ingredients 
              INNER JOIN ingredient_product ON ingredient_product.ingredient_id = ingredients.id 
              WHERE ingredients.id=' . $id . ' ;'))
        ->make(TRUE);
});
```

I get this error:

> POST http://localhost:8080/pizzeria/public/api/ingredients 500 (Internal Server Error) and DataTables warning: table id=ingredientTable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Comment: You never get the id from the post. Also, you should be using parameters instead of attempting to quote your own variable, which leaves you open for SQL injection.

Comment: @aynber `select()` is parameterized, only `DB::raw()` exposes you.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Sending the $id in that format is not parameterized.

Comment: @aynber You're right, it should be `DB::raw()` anyway, that's most likely why the 500 ISE. `select()` is being used incorrectly. I will update my answer to resolve that.

Comment: You can actually use DB::select like that. Something else would be throwing the error.

Comment: Thank you!.. I solved the problem with you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `r` in `Route` should be capitalized

```
Route::post
```

Your `select()` statement is incorrect, as you would need to use `DB::raw()` to allow yourself to write raw SQL. However, as pointed out by @aynber, you would also expose yourself to SQL injection. Instead, it should be done like this:

```
DB::table('ingredients')
    ->join('ingredient_product', 'ingredients.id', 'ingredient_product.ingredients_id')
    ->where('ingredients.id', request()->has('id') ? request()->get('id' : null)
    ->select('*') 
    ->get();
```

This will safeguards you from SQL injection and correctly utilize Laravel's `Query Builder`